# Huge number of packages are about to be deleted after Debian upgrade, how to check list in text mode?

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I am about to upgrade from Debian 11 to 12. I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F3 and entered text mode to ensure a smooth upgrade.

1. Update & Upgrade system

```bash
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

2. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` so that all `bullseye` are now `bookworm`, add new `non-free-firmware` entry
3. Update system

```bash
$ sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt update
```

4. Upgrade system

```bash
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

I just finished `sudo apt upgrade` of step 4, in which over 5000 packages were upgraded. Now I am about to `sudo apt full-upgrade`, but `apt` warning me that ~500 packages will be removed made me pause. I wanted to manually review the list of packages that will be sacrificed. However I realized that I am in text mode so I cannot use the scroll wheel to go back and forth. `apt` prints out the names of packages so fast that it's humanly impossible to grasp, how can I make it possible to navigate the output back and forth?

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from appending it to a file, using CTRL+C, and then reviewing the file?

Comment: Sounds like the console framebuffer scrollback in your kernel is disabled or too small to be useful.  You could set kernel command-line options to increase the scrollback size but that would require rebooting.  Redirecting to a file as @NasirRiley suggests is what I usually do.  Another alternative is to run the `apt full-upgrade` inside `tmux` or `screen` (apt install one of them if they're not already installed - IMO tmux is better unless you're already a long time user of screen), then you could use their scrollback features.

Comment: BTW, with ~500 packages to be removed, there's probably only one package (or a small number of packages) that conflict with something important.  If you can find what that is and hold it (with `apt-mark hold`) or replace it with an alternative that doesn't conflict, you can prevent the cascade of package removals.   `aptitude`'s `why`/ `why-not` sub-command can be useful here, as can aptitude & apt-get's `--simulate` option.

Answer (score 0):

You could try previewing the upgrade with something like

```
apt --dry-run upgrade -y | less
```

And for extra safety, you don't even need to run this as root.